# Which is the correct usage of "and" in American English in this example?

Tags: grammar, american-english, coordinating-conjunctions

**Scenario 1**

A series of unfortunate events has led Makoto "Edamame" Edamura to adopt the life of crime—pickpocketing and scamming others for a living. However, after swindling a seemingly clueless tourist, Makoto discovers that he was the one tricked **and, to make matters worse,** the police are now after him.

**Scenario 2**

A series of unfortunate events has led Makoto "Edamame" Edamura to adopt the life of crime—pickpocketing and scamming others for a living. However, after swindling a seemingly clueless tourist, Makoto discovers that he was the one tricked **, and to make matters worse,** the police are now after him.

I beleive it is Scenario 2 because "and" is always a coordinating conjunction.

Comment: He discovers that (a) he has been tricked and (b) the police are after him. _To make matters worse_ is just a parenthetical comment and, as such, is separated by commas from the main sentence.

Comment: @KateBunting I can understand that. However, surely that should not overpower "and"'s nature as a coordinating conjunction. "Makoto discovers that he was the one tricked" is a sentence in itself, the "and" serves as an extension and should follow normal grammar rules.

Comment: The comma before and after are separate issues.

Comment: Do  these answer your question? [Comma before 'and' in compound sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42811/comma-before-and-in-compound-sentences) and [Comma placement for a parenthetical after 'and'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/422011/comma-placement-for-a-parenthetical-after-and). One comma or two may not be incorrect, but it would be better to remove some comma-clutter here – perhaps by the use of dashes. It might also be felt necessary to disambiguate.

Comment: Why is this tagged "grammar"? I see no question about English syntax or English morphology.